Optimize two functions on two datasets with shared parameters
I have two functions that share parameters and each function needs to be optimized on separate data. My question is: can I simply add the residual sum of squares for two functions in my objective function?
I will give a toy R code as an example.
eq_1_optim = function(ka,kel,t){return(0.004*(exp(-kel*t)-exp(-ka*t)))}
eq_2_optim = function(kel,t){return(0.004*(exp(-kel*t)))}
Dataset 1: t1=c(0,0.3,0.7,1,1.5,4,6), p1=c(0,2.5,4,4.4,3.8,2,0.9)
Dataset 2: t2=c(0.01,0.1,0.5,1,8), p2=c(0.5,0.4,0.01,0.01,0.004)
t=list(t1,t2)
observ = list(p1,p2)
obj_fun = function(par,t,observed){
t1=t[[1]]
t2=t[[2]]
observed_1 = observed[[1]]
observed_2 = observed[[2]]
predicted_model_1 = eq_1_optim(par[1],par[2],t1)
predicted_model_2 = eq_2_optim(par[2],t2)
rss1 = sum((observed_1-predicted_model_1)^2)
rss2 = sum((observed_2-predicted_model_2)^2)
return(rss1+rss2)}
fit = optim(par=c(5,0.3),fn = obj_fun,t=t,observed=observ,method = "L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0.5,0.01),upper=c(10,10))
Any help is appreciated.
